# Не парсится аргумент командной строки

Tags: c++, qt, парсер

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь парсить аргументы командной строки через QCommandLineParser .

Строка может принимать аргументы `--alphabet , --length`

Lenght парсится хорошо и выводится в консоль без проблем.
[image: Вывод аргумента --length]

Но когда пытаюсь вывести значение аргумента `--alphabet`, то в консоль ничего не выводится.
[image: Вывод аргумента --alphabet]

Конвертирую из `QString` в `std::string` вроде правильно(если ничего не путаю).

Сам парсинг:

```
auto parser = parse_args(QCoreApplication(argc, argv));
auto strat = select_alphabet(*parser);
auto length = parser->value("length").toUInt();
auto alphabet = parser->value("alphabet").toUtf8().data();
cout << alphabet << endl;
```

Вот так добавляю опции :

```
QScopedPointer<QCommandLineParser> parse_args(const QCoreApplication& app) {
    auto parser = new QCommandLineParser;

    parser->setApplicationDescription("Password generator app.");
    parser->addHelpOption();

    parser->addOption({
        "simple",
        "Generates simple password."
    });

    parser->addOption({
        {"medium", "m"},
        "Generates medium complexity password."
    });

    parser->addOption({
        {"strong", "s"},
        "Generates most complex password."
    });

    parser->addOption({
        {"length", "l"},
        "Generates password of specified length.",
        "LENGTH",
        "10"
    });

    parser->addOption({
        {"alphabet", "a"},
        "Generate password with our alphabet"
    });

     parser->addOption({
        {"from","f"},
        "Generate password with our alphabet from file"
    });

    parser->process(app);

    if (!parser->parse(QCoreApplication::arguments()))
        error(parser->errorText().toLatin1().toStdString());

    return QScopedPointer(parser);
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

UPDATE 1
[image: скрин изменения]

Comment: В начале функции main  создается объект  QCoreApplication,, помимо parse_args?

Comment: Видимо нет. А как его создать?

Answer (score 0):

работа с QCommandLineParser не вдаваясь в детали

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCommandLineParser parser;
        QCommandLineOption name_param(QStringList()<<"n"<<"name","Name","default-name");
        QCommandLineOption port_param(QStringList()<<"p"<<"port","Port","default-port");
        parser.addOption(name_param);
        parser.addOption(port_param);
        parser.process(a);

        if(parser.isSet(name_param))
            qDebug()<<"name is " << parser.value(name_param);
        if(parser.isSet(port_param))
            qDebug()<<"port is " << parser.value(port_param);
```

Касаемо вашего случая

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QCommandLineParser parser;
    QCommandLineOption opt_simple(QStringList()<<"s"<<"simple","Generates simple password."); // опция не требует значения
    QCommandLineOption opt_medium(QStringList()<<"m"<<"medium","Generates medium complexity password.");
    QCommandLineOption opt_strong(QStringList()<<"S"<<"strong","Generates most complex password.");
    QCommandLineOption opt_alphabet(QStringList()<<"a"<<"alphabet","Generate password with our alphabet");
    QCommandLineOption opt_from(QStringList()<<"f"<<"from","Generate password with our alphabet from file.","FILE","");
    QCommandLineOption opt_length(QStringList()<<"l"<<"length","Generates password of specified length.","LENGTH","10"); // значение по умолчанию 10
    parser.addOption(opt_simple);
    parser.addOption(opt_medium);
    parser.addOption(opt_strong);
    parser.addOption(opt_alphabet);
    parser.addOption(opt_from);
    parser.addOption(opt_length);
    parser.addHelpOption(); // добавим опцию помощи (--help выведет помощь по использованию и завершит приложение)
    parser.process(a);

    // Переберем все опции, которые переданы в командной строке
    foreach(QString opt,parser.optionNames()){
            qDebug()<<opt<<" was set with value "<<parser.value(opt); // выведем название опции и значение (если его нет, будет "")
    }
    if(!parser.isSet("s")&&!parser.isSet("m")&&!parser.isSet("S")){ // проверим что была установлена хотябы одна опция режима
        qDebug()<<"mode was not set";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать как это поможет решить мою проблему?
Я новичок, и еще многого не понимаю, так что прошу не ругать))

Comment: см. выше. дополнил ответ

Comment: Попробовал сделать как вы сказали, ошибка осталась. Не могу вывести значение аргумента --alphabet . --length выводит нормально , а аргумент --alphabet выводит всегда "".

Comment: Дополнил вопрос (прикрепил скрин)

Comment: смотрите инициализацию opt_length и opt_alphabet. первый предполагает наличие параметра, второй - нет

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. 
Добавить параметр "TEXT" в

```
parser->addOption({
        {"alphabet", "a"},
        "Generate password with our alphabet"
    });
```

Верный вариант :

```
parser->addOption({
        {"alphabet", "a"},
        "Generate password with our alphabet",
        "TEXT"
    });
```